# On the golang call DLL?

Tags: c++, c, windows, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

const (
    PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION = 1 << 10
    PROCESS_VM_READ           = 1 << 4
)

//defind a struct
type PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS struct {
    cb                         uint32
    PageFaultCount             uint32
    PeakWorkingSetSize         uint64
    WorkingSetSize             uint64
    QuotaPeakPagedPoolUsage    uint64
    QuotaPagedPoolUsage        uint64
    QuotaPeakNonPagedPoolUsage uint64
    QuotaNonPagedPoolUsage     uint64
    PagefileUsage              uint64
    PeakPagefileUsage          uint64
}

func main() {
    //get Process Handle
    current, err := syscall.OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, false, 728)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    //call psapi.ll
    psapi := syscall.NewLazyDLL("psapi.dll")
    var process PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS
    process.cb = uint32(unsafe.Sizeof((process)))
    GetProcessMemoryInfo := psapi.NewProc("GetProcessMemoryInfo")
    _, _, err = GetProcessMemoryInfo.Call(uintptr(current), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&process)), unsafe.Sizeof(&process))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(process)
    }
}
```

Reports this error:

> The data area passed to a system call is too small

Answer (score 0):

`unsafe.Sizeof(&process)` returns the size of the pointer — the address of the memory occupied by the variable `process`.

I suppose you want to use `unsafe.Sizeof(process)` for that.

Comment: Try unsafe.Sizeof(process) ,The same mistake The data area passed to a system call is too small.